Where IN query with 'and' condition is not working
I'm working on a bugfix regarding filters where I can receive 1 or several filters per request. The filters consist of 2 fields: an attribute_id and a value.
The APP is in Laravel.
Example of filters:
[
    [
        attribute_id => '33',
        value => 'A',
    ],
    [
        attribute_id => '31',
        value => '2024',
    ],
]

I have to conditions one is an and and another is or the problem is with and condition
If only one of them exists, I should receive nothing ([]), but if both exist, I should get the results, and this is where it's failing. I would like to do something like this but I know but without create another inner join with alias:
SELECT
  `contacts`.* 
FROM
  `contacts` 
INNER JOIN 
  `contact_attributes`
  ON `contact_attributes`.`contact_id` = `contacts`.`id` 
WHERE
  `contacts`.`company_id` = 7
  AND (
    `contact_attributes`.`attribute_id` = 33
    AND CAST(REPLACE(contact_attributes.value, '"', '') AS CHAR) = ('A')
  )
  AND (
    `contact_attributes`.`attribute_id` = 31
    AND CAST(REPLACE(contact_attributes.value, '"', '') as CHAR) = ('2024')
  )


Are you having problems with your SQL query or with translating it to Query Builder?

in your case you set conditions on joined table so you need to add the condition in JOIN query
SELECT
  `contacts`.* 
FROM
  `contacts` 
INNER JOIN
  `contact_attributes`
  ON `contact_attributes`.`contact_id` = `contacts`.`id` 
  AND (
    `contact_attributes.id`= 33
    OR `contact_attributes.id` = 31
  )
  WHERE `contacts`.`company_id` = 7

